# Postgres regexp_matches between two patterns

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to split the expression like in Postgres 9.4:
"some text 123_good_345 and other text 123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333 stop."

using pattern: `(\d+\_.*\_\d+\D)+?`
result is:

```
"123_good_345"
"123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333"
```

But I need

```
"123_good_345"
"222_work ok_333"
```

note, ignoring "123_some_invalid"

Please help!

Comment: On what basis do you decide that `222_work` and `ok_333` are part of same match group?

Comment: expression must start with "number + underscore" and end with "underscore + number", but "number + underscore some text number + underscore  ... 
 underscore + number" is wrong

Comment: You need `\d+_(?:(?!\d_).)*_\d+`. See https://regex101.com/r/iq45qc/1 and https://rextester.com/VJJXF1223. See [full answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53748115/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\d+_(?:(?!\d_).)*_\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq45qc/1/). Or, if there can be no digits between `\d+_` and `_\d+`, use

```
\d+_\D+_\d+
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iq45qc/2).

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
  -`_` - an underscore
- `(?:(?!\d_).)*` - any char, 0 or more repetitions, as many as possible, that does not start a digit + `_` char sequence
- `\D+` - any 1+ chars other than digits
- `_` - an underscore
- `\d+` - 1+ digits.

See the [PostgreSQL demo](https://rextester.com/EBK19450):

```
SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('some text 123_good_345 and other text 123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333 stop.', '\d+_(?:(?!\d_).)*_\d+', 'g'));
```

or

```
SELECT unnest(regexp_matches('some text 123_good_345 and other text 123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333 stop.', '\d+_\D+_\d+', 'g'));
```

[image]

Comment: Almost, but it is ok for Postgres 9.6, while in Postgres 9.4 it returns: "123_good_345 and other text 123" for the first line, while second line is correct :-/

Comment: @man2002ua Strange, try `\d+_(?:(?!\d_).)*?_\d+`. Or `\d+_[^_]*_\d+`.

Comment: first suggestion - no changes, second - only last expression shown (but correct)

Comment: @man2002ua What is the code behind that? It is quite clear to me there is something that modifies your input, or you just have an input different from what you posted.

Comment: Yes, input is dynamic. ",  ''9078_null_null_Summary Base TFC POD HRG_fd_in_5825'', ("agg"."agg_30_q")::text, ''9078_null null_6666'', next"

Comment: @man2002ua It "works" [here](https://rextester.com/WKKY68081) if by "works" you mean you need to get `123_good_345`, `222_work ok_333` and `9078_null null_6666`.

Comment: Yes works, but "9078_null_null_Summary Base TFC POD HRG_fd_in_5825" missing :-(

Comment: @man2002ua There is a problem with your pattern requirements then. How is `9078_null_null_Summary Base TFC POD HRG_fd_in_5825` different from `123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333`? You do not want the first and want the second? How?

Comment: pattern start is "number + underscore", pattern end is "underscore + number". Inside can be anything, any chars. In the "123_some_invalid and 222_work ok_333" only one is valid with open and close pattern.

Comment: @man2002ua So you cannot achieve that without a lookakead. `\d+_(?:(?!\d_).)*_\d+` or `\d+_[^0-9]*(?:\d(?!_)[^0-9]*)*_\d+` is what you need, but not sure your sql version supports them.

Comment: trying in rextester.com, still not right. Ok, probably have to use old good parsing.

Comment: Does `'\d+_[^\d]+_\d+'` for you?

Comment: @marcus Works as expected! Thank you.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it is basically the same :)

Comment: @man2002ua But a bit more portable. `[^0-9]*` would be even more portable.

Comment: Thank you for your help